# Spring single Request with multiple transaction does earlier transactional entity becomes detouch

Tags: spring, entity, transactional

In spring framework project > In a single Request I called `foo()` method which is @Transactional and next called `bar()` method which is also @Transactional.

My question is do the entities loaded in `foo()` are still available in the persistance context. My point is, the Transactional is over but persistance context is exist science the hibernate session is still alive science the request is not yet completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have bean *FooBean*:

```
@Component
public class FooBean {
    @Transactional
    public void foo(){}

    @Transactional
    public void bar(){}
}
```

And both methods are called from method *baz* of bean *BazBean*:

```
@Component
public class BazBean {
    public void baz(){
        foo();
        bar();
    }
}
```

If method *baz* already executed in transaction, i.e. it marked as transactional:

```
@Transactional
public void baz(){
```

Or *BazBean* marked as transactional:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class BazBean {
```

Or as transactional marked any method up on calling stack.

Than *foo* and *bar* will be executed in one transaction.

Otherwise *foo* and *bar* will be executed in different transactions.

Please note, that it all was described for *@Transactional* without parameters. See paramteter *propagation* for *@Transactional*: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html

Comment: Thanks that you have written the picture that was suppose to do by me.

Comment: So, wiil the entities loaded in foo() and bar() are still in persistance context or in hibernate session after baz() execution is finished (http request is not still finished) ?

Comment: Persistence context live only during one transaction.

Comment: what do you mean - entities loaded in foo() will die after exiting foo() and so on bar()  - is this ?

Comment: Yes, if you will not have save references to they somewhere outside.